# Does this integral depend on choice of branch cut?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

The Integral is $$\displaystyle \int_C \frac{(ln z)^2}{z^2+1}$$

The problem mentions only that the contour C covers all singularities.

This is obviously $2\pi i $ times the sum of the residues at $\pm i$:

$$\frac{(log \, i)^2}{2i}+\frac{(log (- i))^2}{-2i}$$

Now $log\, z$ is a multivalued function. So naively it would seem that the integral should also depend on the choice of branch cut. For instance if we choose the principal branch with $arg z \in (-\pi,\pi] $ then the integral vanishes. But were we to choose $arg z \in [0,2\pi) $ we would get a non zero result.

Is that correct? Is one of these choices more correct than the other?

Comment: Is it an integral along a particular path? I don't see any specified in the question. There will certainly be a branch point at $z=0$, and the value of the integral will depend on how the path behaves with respect to this branch point too.

Comment: What is the path of integration?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The question mentions only that the path covers all the singularities. Yes there's a branch point at 0.

Comment: @FourierTransform please see my answer to Henning.

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri I would say that Since $\ln(z)$ is multivalued, no need to worry about branch cut.

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri: That's not enough information to evaluate the integral. If you go around the $z=0$ branch point once, you end up _on a different branch_ of the logarithm, and therefore you cannot treat the contour as a closed curve -- in particular, the value of the integral will now depend on _where_ in the complex plane your integral starts and end. (In contrast, for an integral of an univalent holomorphic function you can move the start/endpoint anywhere by an appropriate homotopy of the curve).

Comment: @FourierTransform: On the contrary, _because_ it is multivalued you definitely do need to worry about which branch we're on. For a simpler example, the integral of $\frac{\log z}{z-1}$ along a small circle around $z=1$ will depend on which branch of the logarithm we take, since each branch of the integrand has its own pole at $z=1$ with _different residues_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : So presumably the question meant that the contour should go around the poles only. So let us choose the branch cut along positive or negative real axis and a contour that does not cross the cut but covers the poles. Is there still any ambiguity?

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri: There is still an ambiguity about which of the infinitely many branches your contour lives in. Each branch has its own poles with its own residues.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: If you look at the solution, it is like $(log(i))^2-(log(-i))^2$. So in a given branch they would seem to cancel out if one let arg(z) vary between $-\pi+2k\pi$ to $\pi +2k\pi$. Correct?

Comment: @NirmalyaKajuri: That would be true if the logarithms weren't squared.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps?

$\log(z)$ as a multivalued function on the domain $\mathbb{C}-0$:

- $\log(z) = \log|z| + i \arg(z)$

Hence

- For any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, on the subset of $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ where $z \, / \, |z| \ne \cos(a) + i \sin(a)$ there is an analytic and single valued branch of $\log(z)$ where $\arg(z)$ is chosen in the interval $a < \arg(z) < a + 2 \pi$. (the "branch cut" in this situation is just the ray defined by the equation $z  \, / \, |z| = \cos(a) + i \sin(a)$.)

It works because if $z \, / \, |z| \ne \cos(a) + i \sin(a)$ then, for any choice of $\theta \in \arg(z)$, using the expression $\arg(z) = \{\theta + 2 n \pi \,\bigm|\, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, it follows that there exists a unique $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\theta + 2 n \pi \in (a,a+2\pi)$.

Comment: The thing is, the answer seems to depend on whether we choose arg(z) to vary between $a$ and $a+2\pi$ or $a-\pi$ and $a+\pi$.